# How do I POST a JSON body AND a Video file to an API endpoint on JMeter?

Tags: rest, http, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

I'm unable to send both, JSON body data and a video/image file together in one request on JMeter. It gives a 401 unauthorized, even though I have added the Authorization header in the HTTP Header Manager. The same request with headers works fine on Postman.

I've already referred to this guide here with no luck.

https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/testing-advanced-rest-api-file-uploads-jmeter/

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data

{
    "email": "xyz@gmail.com",
    "password": "xyz",
    "file": ${__FileToString("/Downloads/SampleVideo_1280x720_1mb.mp4")}

}
```

**SAMPLER RESULT:**

```
Thread Name: Thread Group 1-1
Sample Start: 2019-09-30 14:26:25 IST
Load time: 2922
Connect Time: 838
Latency: 2922
Size in bytes: 202
Sent bytes:1056397
Headers size in bytes: 202
Body size in bytes: 0
Sample Count: 1
Error Count: 1
Data type ("text"|"bin"|""): 
Response code: 401
Response message: Unauthorized


HTTPSampleResult fields:
ContentType: 
DataEncoding: null
```

**REQUEST:**

```
POST data:
--o3F8APyqP080W3wk0N_-96jzl11Bfsa
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="SampleVideo_1280x720_1mb.mp4"
Content-Type: video/mp4
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

<actual file content, not shown here>
--o3F8APyqP080W3wk0N_-96jzl11Bfsa--


[no cookies]
```

Answer (score 0):

JMeter should be doing what real browser (or other application using your API endpoint) is doing.

If the browser (or the application) sends 2 requests - JMeter must be sending 2 requests as well. If the browser (or the application) sends 1 request - JMeter must be sending 1 request. In case of 1 request my expectation is that you should be sending [`application/json`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#MIME_type) as the value of the [Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) header like it's done in the guide you're referring.

```
--boundary
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8



JSON Metadata
--boundary
Content-Type: file MIME type



File content
--boundary--
```

The answer is quite simple: just **record** the request using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) and JMeter will come up with proper configuration of the HTTP Request sampler(s), [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager), etc. All you will need to do is to implement [parameterization and correlation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start) so the script could be replayed successfully.

One important bit: during the recording you need to have `SampleVideo_1280x720_1mb.mp4` file in JMeter's "bin" folder as modern [browsers don't return the full path](https://davidwalsh.name/fakepath) hence JMeter will be able to properly capture the file upload request only if the file lives in its "bin" folder. More information: [Recording File Uploads with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/recording-file-uploads-jmeter/)

Comment: Thanks for your response Dmitri! The browser sends only 1 request with the json body and the video file, I tried on postman and it works. But when I try the same on jmeter it does not. I was trying to check if the body data is getting passed to the request, but it does not.

The problem with adding the content type as mentioned in the guide above is that it still fails and gives a 401, even after I've tried that.

Comment: As mentioned here:
```
--boundary
Content-Type: file MIME type



File content
--boundary--
```

What do I add in the file content? When i tried to use the FileToString function, it does not work

Comment: If you're able to run the request in browser and in postman you should be able to record the request in JMeter. Maybe the file body is encoded / compressed somehow

Comment: Apart from recording the request, is there any other solution to this? I tried using the Recorder but it is a mobile application and was unable to record even after following the tutorials on recording on a mobile application.

Comment: It should be normally possible to record mobile applications, you just need to install JMeter's certificate onto the device. On Android 7+ you will also need to take some extra steps, check out [Recording Using Android Devices](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000285357-Recording-Using-Android-Devices-Recording-Using-Android-Devices) article for more details

Answer (score 0):

To post json body and attachment you can add your "email" and "password" in **Parameters** tab of JMeter HTTPS request and file in **Files Upload** tab.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but it does not work. see my comments above.

Comment: can you share the header you added to Jmeter and whats been added to postman for successful request?